# Why won't a transaction with 888/byte confirm after 11+ hours?

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions, transaction-fees, child-pays-for-parent

I have this transaction that I can't figure out why it won't confirm.

https://blockchain.info/tx/92b33d498a35d47f03eee14f258cf9b3f015a5d12856eb05e47534e664344239

If I check https://bitcoinfees.earn.com/#delay it says with that it should confirm very quickly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won't confirm because the [grandparent](https://blockchain.info/tx/9ad0b2b19705c10c510743fa3be06e743f25e629f1bd5b9e2ffcbf3b01ba2672) and [parent](https://blockchain.info/tx/110fef140bb6d6109942c939b3bb7f9bc46a480db01bb1562dfa51bf62b58775) of your child transaction aren't confirmed. The grandparent transaction was also paid with a really low fee(51.573 sat/B).

I did the math for you.

```
Grandparent + parent + child = total transaction size:
3878 Bytes + 226 Bytes + 225 Bytes = 4329 Bytes

Add up all paid fees:
200000 Sat + 200000 Sat + 200000 Sat  = 600000 sat

Divide total paid fees with total transaction size:
600000 / 4329 = 138.6 Sat/B

Subtract to find difference needed:
450 Sat/B - 138.6 Sat/B = 311.4 missing Sat/B
```

To sum it up.
On average, the three transactions were paid with a fee of 138.6 Sat/B each.
The fee needed to confirm within 6 blocks is presumably [around 450 Sat/B](https://estimatefee.com/) right now.
So the three transactions are short 311.4 Sat/B to reach the target of 450 Sat/B.

Comment: Probably Rob can use reaplace-by-fee in this case to make it faster.

Comment: How can I do that?  I used blockchain.info api to make the transaction

Comment: where can I see the parent / gradnparent - transactions on blockchain.info?

Comment: @Rob You can't on most exchanges, however your fee of 138.6 Sat/B will confirm within 48-144 blocks...seems like it just got confirmed now.

Comment: @Alpha just follow the trails where the unconfirmed outputs originate from.